# Vimeo default video size

Tags: javascript, html, embed, vimeo

I am trying to embed a number of different Vimeo players, which feature video content at different resolutions. I want the dimensions of each player be identical to that of it's respective video, so no letter boxing / black border appears around the edges. I'd have thought this would happen automatically, but every player I've embedded defaults to the same size, regardless of the dimensions of the video.

Does anybody know a way to either solve this simply, or pull the dimensions of the video itself so I could set the player's height dynamically?

I'm using the Iframe embed method.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When working with different resolutions and browser sizes, best solution currently using JavaScript. Here's a jQuery plugin called [FitVids](http://fitvidsjs.com/) that I would recommend.

How you would use it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // use div container that contains all your videos
    $(document.body).fitVids();
});
```